# filling up 2 x n array with dominos

Tags: arrays, combinatorics

i have to write the method:

`public int domino(int num)`

i have a two-dimensional integer array with `2 x num` size(`2` rows and `num` columns)

i need to find how many ways i can fill up the board with domino blocks

(each domino fills up 2 cells that are touching and not diagonal)

i'm supposed to use recursion to do this but

i hink that maybe there is a way to just do this:

```
return(some sort of combinatorics formula )
```

is there a formula for this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by simple recurrence method. Assume `T(n)` is number of ways in which a 2 x n board can be filled.

Now consider the top left most cell. The domino covering this can be oriented in 2 possible ways.

1) Horizontal 2) Vertical

In case 1, since that domino is horizontal, the below cells must also be filled by a horizontal domino. After this, there remains a 2 x (n-2) board which can be filled in `T(n-2)` ways.

In the second case, there remains a 2 x (n-1) board which can be filled in `T(n-1)` ways.

So the total number of ways of filling a 2 x n board is

`T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)` and the base case is, T(1) = 1 which can be verified easily.

It is basically the **fibonacci recurrence** which has a closed form solution.